# Yii2 after composer update returns 500

Tags: angularjs, yii2, composer-php

I'm developing an applicaiton using Yii2 and AngularJS. I've tried to do `composer update` but after this command something weird happened. Yii2 is returning data as JSON as it should but response status code is 500, and I have no idea what went wrong on composer update.I am using apache server. Function `error_get_last()` returns NULL.

**Update**

I've found error in server logs it's:
`Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method yii\\helpers\\ArrayHelper::filter() in private/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Target.php:136`

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/log/Target.php#L136

Comment: Verify if this class can be accessed at all.

Comment: Yes, I am using ArrayHelper::index in my app and it's working, when i've pasted this method (filter) to Target class and called it as self everything started working, but it is not a solution.

Comment: in other instance of app, before composer update Target class is the same and it also uses ArrayHelper::filter and everything works fine... I have no idea what is messed up.

Comment: Is there any chance you have got this class remapped with some custom implementation? Like using [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html#class-map).

Comment: no. I don't see anything like this in code.

Comment: Ok, i've found solution, it was overwritten.
This function helped:
$reflector = new \ReflectionClass('yii\helpers\BaseArrayHelper');
var_dump($reflector->getFileName());

Comment: HA! I knew it! :)

Comment: tanks  for help;)